# Dropdown values for django form not showing up in view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to make a todo app in django but I am not able to get a dropdown to set a category populate.

This is what the form looks like when I render everything:
[image]

What I am expecting was that the dropdown would have the options 'Personal' and 'Professional'

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (('Personal', 'Personal'), ('Professional', 'Professional'))
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type


class Item(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{self.created_at}: {self.task}")
```

This is the form I am trying to use:

```
from .models import Item
from django import forms


class AddItem(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['task', 'category']
```

This is the template:

```
<div>
  <h1>Your todo task</h1>
  <br>
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'home' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Add a task</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time and any information you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [video](https://youtu.be/zF0t666RZAY?t=1883) (timestamped) answered my question.

In the end I think using a tuple for the list was not the right call, specifically this part:

```
    CATEGORY = (('Personal', 'Personal'), ('Professional', 'Professional'))
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
```

It was better to have it be a char field and then just add the categories through the admin panel.